# Linux Kernel run sparse failed - /bin/sh: 1: sparse: not found

Tags: linux-kernel

I run sparse on linux kernel.

But it throws the following error:

> Run sparse on linux:
>   lovegcy@knltest-VirtualBox:~/git_root/linux$ make C=2
>   make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>     HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o
>     HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_64.o
>     HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_common.o
>     HOSTLD  arch/x86/tools/relocs
>     CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
>     CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
>     CC      kernel/bounds.s
>     GEN     include/generated/bounds.h
>     CC      arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.s
>     GEN     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
>     CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
>     CHECK   scripts/mod/empty.c
>   **/bin/sh: 1: sparse: not found**
>   make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
>
>   make[1]:**  [scripts/mod] Error 2
>   make: ** [scripts] Error 2

Here is the sparse install log:

> lovegcy@knltest-VirtualBox:~/git_root/sparse$ make install
>   /bin/sh: 1: llvm-config: not found
>   Makefile:79: Your system does not have llvm, disabling sparse-llvm
>        INSTALL  ‘sparse’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/bin/sparse’
>        INSTALL  ‘cgcc’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/bin/cgcc’
>        INSTALL  ‘c2xml’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/bin/c2xml’
>        INSTALL  ‘test-inspect’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/bin/test-inspect’
>        INSTALL  ‘sparse.1’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/share/man/man1/sparse.1’
>        INSTALL  ‘cgcc.1’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/share/man/man1/cgcc.1’
>        INSTALL  ‘libsparse.a’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/lib/libsparse.a’
>        INSTALL  ‘token.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/token.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘parse.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/parse.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘lib.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/lib.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘symbol.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/symbol.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘scope.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/scope.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘expression.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/expression.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘target.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/target.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘linearize.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/linearize.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘bitmap.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/bitmap.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘ident-list.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/ident-list.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘compat.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/compat.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘flow.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/flow.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘allocate.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/allocate.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘storage.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/storage.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘ptrlist.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/ptrlist.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘dissect.h’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/include/sparse/dissect.h’
>        INSTALL  ‘sparse.pc’ -> ‘/home/lovegcy/lib/pkgconfig/sparse.pc’

More:
The kernel is already compiled.

Could anyone give some clue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Easier method :

First, download and Install **`sparse`** on your host-PC from the official channel.

For example, on Ubuntu run,
`$ sudo apt-get install sparse`

---

#### Building from source:

Alternately if you are attempting to build `sparse` from its sources, then we need to ensure that after running the `make install` command the `sparse` binary is present at `/usr/bin/sparse`.

This can be confirmed by opening a new terminal and running the `which sparse` command in it. It should output similar to the following :

```
$ which sparse
/usr/bin/sparse
```

In the same terminal, navigate to the Linux kernel source directory and attempt `make C=2` to run `sparse` on the Linux kernel source.

**Note** : From your logs it appears that `sparse` is being installed into `/home/lovegcy/bin/`. Ensure that you have added the path `/home/lovegcy/bin/` your `$PATH` environment variable. Otherwise the system will NOT be able to find the `sparse` binary.

On Ubuntu (running the bash shell), this can be automated for each new terminal by adding the following line in the `.bashrc` file as follows :

```
$ echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/home/lovegcy/bin/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Either to install sparse or build from source are working.