# bitbake build can't find sparse

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to compile the kernel module inside Yocto recipe. However, I always get this error `/bin/sh: 1: sparse: not found`.
 If I cross-compile the module with the populated SDK, it works perfectly fine.

Somehow, `sh` can't find `sparse`.
Note: `sparse` is downloaded

Here is my recipe

```
SUMMARY = "test Linux kernel module"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit module

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/xyz/test_yocto.git;protocol=https"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
#SRCREV = "5c6224fee66d8e4eb167f4c74d42e5cfa479e9eb"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

# The inherit of module.bbclass will automatically name module packages with
# "kernel-module-" prefix as required by the oe-core build environment.

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-test"
```

and here is my make file:

```
obj-m := test.o

SRC := $(shell pwd)

all:
        $(MAKE) KBUILD_CHECKSRC=1 -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC)

modules_install:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
        rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
        rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
```

If I remove `KBUILD_CHECKSRC=1`, which will pass checks, it will work fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Kernel run sparse failed - /bin/sh: 1: sparse: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139000/linux-kernel-run-sparse-failed-bin-sh-1-sparse-not-found)

Comment: No at all not. `sparse` is downloaded on my build machine. I can build the module with the `SDK` and it uses `sparse`. However, this cant be done during bitbake build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a kernel expert but this seems pretty clear: When you define `KBUILD_CHECKSRC=1` the module build uses an external tool called 'sparse'. This tool is not currently a build dependency for the kernel module so the build fails.

You can either avoid using KBUILD_CHECKSRC (and this is probably what you want: KBUILD_CHECKSRC sounds like something your module developers should be using). Alternatively you can add "sparse-native" to your module recipes DEPENDS and then make sure you are using a layer that provides that ([layers.openembedded.org says meta-sca has it](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/104529/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought it would use sparse from my build machine.